# rails, fancybox not working in heroku production

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, heroku, fancybox

i have fancybox working in my dev environment perfectly, but when i push to Heroku production, it doesn't work. I've tried looking at all the help on here (precompiling assets, etc.), tried everything, but can't seem to get it to work! Hope someone can help me here...

here is my application.html.erb:

```
<html>
<head>
    <%= analytics_init if Rails.env.production? %>

    <%= favicon_link_tag "/favicon.ico" %>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Code+Pro:200,300,400,500,600,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <!-- Add jQuery library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

  <!-- WORLD MAP -->
  <link href="/assets/jqvmap.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="/assets/jquery.vmap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/jquery.vmap.world.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  

  <!-- Add fancyBox -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <%= render "layouts/header" unless @disable_header %>
  <%=yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

my application.js:

```
//= require rails_autocomplete
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.fancybox
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require turbolinks
//= require bxslider
//= require fancybox
//= require_tree .

var fancybox = function(){
    $('.fancybox').fancybox({ 
        parent: "body",
        helpers: {
            overlay: {
                locked: false
            }
        }
    });         
};
$(document).on("page:load ready", fancybox);
```

If someone sees something that I don't, that would be great - or at least point me in the direction of how I can debug this in Heroku Production. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, if you can just share your application.js file then it would be better to answer your problem.

Comment: No problem - edited original post. Again, I have it working fine in development, but Heroku Production is not working. When I click the Fancybox link, it simply goes to another page, and displays the picture.

Comment: It seems because if you will start the app in production mode your app will get some js twice on the web page, because you defined them twice one at application.html and another one is application.js please make all unique, check them.

Comment: Hmm so which code should I be deleting?

Comment: Delete all javascript and css, which you loaded in the application.html ?

Comment: i deleted the fancybox and jquery library from application.html and still does not work in production... any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

after playing around a little bit, looks like I had to move the whole script in my application.js file into the view. Not sure why this works - but if someone knows why this would impact production, please let everyone know! Thanks!